# Skipping the first term of a compound index by using hint()

Tags: mongodb

Suppose I have a Mongo collection with fields `a` and `b`.  I've populated this collection with `{a:'a', b : index }` where `index` increases iteratively from 0 to 1000.

I know this is very, very wrong, but can't explain (no pun intended) why:

`collection.find({i:{$gt:500}}).explain()` confirms that the index was not used (I can see that it scanned all 1,000 documents in the collection).

[image]

Somehow forcing Mongo to use the index seems to work though:

`collection.find({i:{$gt:500}}).hint({a:1,i:1}).explain()`

[image]

**Edit**
The Mongo documentation is very clear that it will only use compound indexes if one of your query terms is the matches the first term of the compound index.  In this case, using hint, it appears that Mongo used the compound index `{a:1,i:1}` even though the query terms do NOT include `a`.  Is this true?

Comment: It is the order of the fields within the compound index, if you put `i` first it will work. Many say that the order doesn't matter but it actually does

Comment: @Sammaye - the index will clearly be used if `i` is put first.  The question here is more about whether or not using hint() allows me to force Mongo to use a compound index even though the query may not contain the first element in the compound index.

Comment: Yea the index can be used if you hint, though it is plain luck that it is a performant one, 90% of the time you will find that if the optimiser cannot pick a performant index the next compound index that should work might cause undue nscanned. I would also note that hint forces an index to be loaded even if it is not particularly good for the query. The optimiser automatically assumes that if it cannot match a compound index on the frist field that it would not be very performant, I think there is some change in line for that.

Comment: @Sammaye - "The optimiser automatically assumes that if it cannot match a compound index on the frist field that it would not be very performant, I think there is some change in line for that."  With my limited understanding of how indexing works, I think you could unequivocally say that a compound index that does not match on the first field would cause a scan of that first index, which dependending on the selectivity of the index, may make the whole thing somewhat bad.  If the first index has high selectivity and is unused by the query, the scan would not be very costly?

Answer (score 0):

The interesting part about the way MongoDB performs queries is that it actually may run multiple queries in parallel to determine what is the best plan. It may have chosen to not use the index due to other experimenting you've done from the shell, or even when you added the data and whether it was in memory, etc/ (or a few other factors). Looking at the performance numbers, it's not reporting that using the index was actually any faster than not (although you shouldn't take much stock in those numbers generally). In this case, the data set is really small.

But, more importantly, according to the MongoDB docs, the output from the hinted run also suggests that the query wasn't [covered](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/indexes/#indexes-covered-queries) entirely by the index (`indexOnly=false`).

That's because your index is `a:1, i:1`, yet the query is for `i`. [Compound indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/#index-type-compound) only support searches based on any prefix of the indexed fields (meaning they must be in the order they were specified).

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-operations/#query-optimization

FYI: Use the [verbose](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/#cursor.explain) option to see a report of all plans that were considered for the find().

Comment: What I am surprised at is the explain of the second command indicated that Mongo was in fact able to use the {a:1,i:1} index (presumably because I hinted it) even though the query parameters were NOT a prefix of the indexed fields.  Is it truly using the index?

Comment: It says it is (based on the fact the cursor is shown to be a Btree).